# docker-compose build with Dockerfile containing experimental feature

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using ssh forwarding experimental feature of Docker in my Dockerfile.

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=gitlab <command>
```

I can build the Dockerfile with

```
docker build --ssh gitlab=<path to file>
```

As part of the docker-compose file

```
build:
  context: <path>
  dockerfile: <filename>
image: imagename:tag
```

when I build using

```
docker-compose build <service name>
```

I get error

```
ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 28: Unknown flag: mount
```

I have no idea what to do. It is a pain to do individual build on every service.
Is there a way I can call *docker-compose build* with an experimental feature?

Comment: Last I checked it’s not supported ref. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440 - build the container with docker.

Comment: @masseyb Thanks for the link. An experimental feature should be at least usable where it is used. I never thought someone could partially implement it for *docker build* but not for *docker-compose build* :(

Comment: Dear @CodeWeed, Got any solution with this problem? Because I think we are already having version 1.25.5

Answer (score 1):

Compose support for connecting to the Docker Engine using the ssh protocol [was added](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6865#issuecomment-546929648) in [version 1.25.0-rc3](https://github.com/docker/compose/tree/bump-1.25.0-rc3?files=1).

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question if that helps someone.

It looks like it will be implemented in *docker-compose version 1.25.RC3*

Answer (score -1):

i tried building dcker image with kaniko getting the same error how to overcome this error while building the docker image using kaniki

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.